# SpringBoot: create object from generic type in generic mapper

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, generics

I have a lot of entity extend `Catalog` entity and as well as have a lot of dto that extent `CatalogDto`

[image: Catalog Entity]

And I have a generic repository, service, and mapper as follows

My repository:

```
@Repository
public interface CatalogRepository<T extends Catalog> extends JpaRepository<T, Integer>{
}
```

My service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CatalogServiceImpl<T extends Catalog,Dto extends CatalogDto>{
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CatalogServiceImpl.class);

    private final CatalogRepository<T> repository;
    private CatalogMapper<T,Dto> catalogMapper=new CatalogMapper<T,Dto>() {};

    public CatalogServiceImpl(CatalogRepository<T> repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }
}
```

My Mapper:

```
public abstract class CatalogMapper<T extends Catalog,Dto extends CatalogDto> implements Rapper<T,Dto> {
    @Override
    public Dto entityToDto(T entity) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public T dtoToEntity(Dto dto) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want to create an object from T in `dtoToEntity` method and an object from Dto in `entityToDto` method in `CatalogMapper` class

Comment: _I tried different methods but I could not do that_ exactly which and how?

Answer (score 2):

I think that these two methods should be abstract because every mapper probably works in different ways. Anyway you can provide a base implementation like this

```
public T dtoToEntity(Dto dto) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    T entity = (T) ((Class)((ParameterizedType)this.getClass().
               getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]).newInstance();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(dto, entity);
    return entity;
}

public Dto entityToDto(T entity) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    Dto dto = (Dto) ((Class)((ParameterizedType)this.getClass().
               getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[1]).newInstance();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(entity, dto);
    return dto;
}
```

Using **ParameterizedType** of the generic class you can create a new instance and then execute a simple copyProperties

Comment: Thank you, but an error occurs at runtime. `sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class at ***.mapper.CatalogMapper.dtoToEntity`